# How to insert a value based on two cells within a row (Dataframe)?

Tags: python, dataframe, insert, row, cell

I have the following Dataframe:
[Dataframe layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjK7y.jpg)

I have the following written:

```
if (df_.loc[(df_['Camera'] == camera1) & (df_['Return'].isnull())]):
    df_.loc[(df_['Camera'] == camera1) & (df_['Return'].isnull()), 'Return'] = time_
    df_.to_csv(csv_file, index=False)
else:
    df_ = df_.append(dfin, ignore_index = True)
    df_.to_csv(csv_file, index=False)
    ...
```

camera1 being input from the user and time_ being todays date/time.

When user input is submitted, first condition would check if input is in the first column 'Camera', and second condition checks if the column with name 'Return' is empty, if true add the current date/time (time_), else create new row with the new info.

Just looking for on how to add the time_ value into the row were user input is already in the dataframe and if the 'Return' column is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get what I wanted with the following:

```
def check():
    set = df_.loc[(df_['Camera'] == camera1) & (df_['Return'].isnull())]
    if set.size != 0:
        return set.iat[0,4]
    else:
        pass
```

Then:

```
if check():
    df_.loc[(df_['Camera'] == camera1) & (df_['Return'].isnull()), 'Return'] = time_
    df_.to_csv(csv_file, index=False)
#....
```